# How to rebuild a large FULLTEXT index with frequent updates

Tags: mysql, triggers, indexing, locking, myisam

We have a MyISAM table with about 20GB of data, with FULLTEXT index. We have several triggers which manipulate that table, which get called about 10 times per second. Now we want to run OPTIMIZE TABLE to rebuild the index. AFAIK OPTIMIZE TABLE locks the table for writes. So what happens to the queries created by the triggers, if OPTIMIZE TABLE takes about 6 hours? Is it a problem? Will queries get dropped after some time? Or what else can we do to rebuild the index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the table is locked, no writes can occur to the table. Any triggers attempting to write will hang until they get a lock-wait timeout.

You can use [pt-online-schema-change](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/pt-online-schema-change.html) to do a table restructure without blocking access to the original table.

Otherwise, configure a pair of servers in master-master replication, do the optimize table on the second master, then swap their roles and do the optimize table on the first master.

Comment: so using pt-online-schema-change --alter "ENGINE=MyISAM" will recreate the index if I understand correct?

Comment: Yes, a table restructure rebuilds *all* the indexes on the table.

Comment: when I try `pt-online-schema-change --execute --alter "ADD FULLTEXT (post)"` I get the error: `Cannot chunk the original table db.table: There is no good index and the table is oversized. at /usr/bin/pt-online-schema-change line 5441, <STDIN> line 2`. Creating that missing index without locking was what I was trying to do.

Comment: Sounds like you don't have a primary key or unique key on this table, which is not good table design. You may be out of luck in avoiding a table lock in this case. Sorry!

Comment: I avoided creating a primary key because this table is only used for match against queries, but if it is need by the tool I can create one, should be pretty fast compared to creating the fulltext index.

Answer (score 0):

There are more and better options.  (1) Set "concurrent_insert = 1" for MyISAM. (2) Use InnoDB, which has optimized fulltext search indexing.  This summary based on what I have read here..

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36666/bypass-myisam-table-lock